# google cloud RDP forwarding

Tags: google-cloud-platform, centos, firewall, iptables, portforwarding

I try to configure google cloud virtual machine to forward RDP to other IP address.
It is because I need to access windows machine via RDP that is not listening on standard 3389 port that I have open, but on other port 50000

It should look something like that:
Work_PC(can only use 3389 port) -> gcs instance listening on port 3389 forward to -> destination windows machine listening RDP on 50000 port.

So I create new-clean Centos 7 micro machine (free tier VM instance google cloud) and I do this steps to setup firewall:

Disable firewalld:

```
1. sudo systemctl stop firewalld
2. sudo systemctl disable firewalld
3. sudo systemctl mask --now firewalld
```

Install iptable-services:

```
1. sudo yum install iptables-services
2. sudo systemctl start iptables
3. sudo systemctl enable iptables
```

**sudo systemctl status iptables** returns:

```
*iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2020-03-09 21:16:50 UTC; 27s ago
 Main PID: 1487 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)*

 *systemd[1]: Starting IPv4 firewall with iptables...
 iptables.init[1487]: iptables: Applying firewall rules: [  OK  ]
 Started IPv4 firewall with iptables.*
```

Enable port forwarding:

```
1.sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Setup iptables:

```
1. sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination DESTINATION_IP:50000
2. sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
3. sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
4. sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 50000 -j ACCEPT
5. (delete default rejection for forward) sudo iptables -D FORWARD 1
```

**iptables -L look like this:**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination

ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere

ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination

ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ms-wbt-server

ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:50000


Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination
```

**sudo iptables -t nat -L look like:**

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination

DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ms-wbt-server to:DESTINATION_IP:50000

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination

MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

**When I try telnet to see if the port is open:**

```
telnet GCS_IP_ADRESS 3389
Trying GCS_IP_ADRESS...
telnet: connect to address GCS_IP_ADRESS: Connection refused*
```

**When I try nmap to see if port is open:**

```
nmap -p 3389 GCS_IP_ADRESS

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
3389/tcp filtered ms-wbt-server

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.31 seconds
```

I can't connect via RDP. Connection is refused...
Can you help me, what do I need to setup to open port 3389 and forward it to destination windows machine??
Thank you

**UPDATE:
Do you know what is really weird? I made exactly same setup on Centos 6 and it is working. Does Centos 7 have any different security or other restriction?**

Comment: Have you considered using SSH tunneling? Very easy to do with a simple command line: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example